# E-olymp: Cake. Giving Wrong Answer

Tags: c++, mathematical-optimization

[Cake](http://www.e-olymp.com/en/problems/112) This is a `e-olymp` programming question.

> In honor of the birth of an heir Tutti royal chef has prepared a huge cake, that was put on the table for Three Fat Man. The first fat man can eat the cake by himself for t1 hours, second - for t2 hours, and the third - for t3 hours.
>
> For what time can the cake be eaten simultaneously by all three fat men?

While I am submitting in normal `Gnu C++` then it is giving 27% accurate result and when I am submitting in Gnu `C++ 4.7.1` then it is giving 8% accurate result?? What is the problem?? Is it my fault?? Help please.

My code:

```
#include<iostream>
#include<cstdio>

using namespace std;

int main()
{

    double t1, t2, t3;
    scanf("%lf %lf %lf", &t1, &t2, &t3);

    double ans=(t1/3.0)+(t2/3.0)+(t3/3.0);
    ans=(ans/3.0);
    printf("%.2lf\n", ans);
    return 0;

}
```

Comment: You should add 'speed', not duration.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My approach was wrong. 
Just I have to use this rules:
`t1` hours/cake = `1/t1` cakes/hour.

For all three, they eat `1/t1+1/t2+1/t3` cakes in one hour.

In h hours, they eat `h(1/t1+1/t2+1/t3)` cakes.

The time to eat a whole cake must satisfy `h(1/t1+1/t2+1/t3)=1` or `h=1/(1/t1+1/t2+1/t3).`

And code will be:

```
double t1, t2, t3;
scanf("%lf %lf %lf", &t1, &t2, &t3);

double ans=1/((1/t1)+(1/t2)+(1/t3));
printf("%.2lf\n", ans);
```

Answer (score 1):

Your logic is wrong.

Imagine that the first person could eat the entire cake in 1 hour.

If the other two people helped, the cake would get finished *sooner*.   It would take **less than one hour**.

Here is an input that would simulate that scenario.

```
1 999 999
```

You program calculates the time required as

```
((1/3.0)+(999/3.0)+(999/3.0)/3.0)
```

That's `444.33` hours.

Comment: @NafeeurRahman I feel like I *have* helped.  Regardless, I do not wish to defeat the purpose of that website.  Good luck!